# How to map user defined web page url to specific html in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

`localhost:8080/company/home`  => Will Open home.html (say it is located in ../resources/static/)
`localhost:8080/company/userdetails` => user.html

I have seen a lot of online resources. But I couldn't understand clearly. Please someone help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example for home.html:

```
@Controller
public class HomePageController {

    @GetMapping("/company/home")
    public String openHomePage() {


        return "home"; // it is your home.html in your /resources/static folder.
    }

}
```

Comment: I am getting the following exception.
`javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [home]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/company/home] again. Check your ViewResolver setup!`
I think it is overriding the default view resolver. Can you tell me how to configure the view resolver to my view.

Comment: I think you need add any engine template for your project, it will be the simplest way. Check jTwig or Thymeleaf for Spring Boot. You can check if it works by adding `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.jtwig</groupId> 
<artifactId>jtwig-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
 <version>5.87.0.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>`

To your pom.xml, and change home.html to home.twig.

Comment: Thank you. After adding thymleaf the problem is solved.